# Determining amount of forest in overlapping buffers using ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, land-use, buffer

I'm using the multiple buffer tool around a series of points for buffer distances 250 m, 500 m and 1000 m around each point. I am then using the tabulate area tool to determine the amount of forest cover from a land cover map within each buffer ring around each point. What I wanted to ensure is that within each buffer zone, such as the 500 m buffer zone that also contains the 250 m buffer zone, is including the amount of forest cover both within the entire 500 m buffer zone area, and is including the forest cover within the embodied 250 m buffer zone as well? I want to make sure it's including the cover in the entire buffer zone for each distance, and isn't excluding what has already been measured in the smaller, overlapping rings.

Comment: If you use the Dissolve_Option="NONE" on the Multi Ring Buffer tool, larger buffers will cover the smaller ones, and any subsequent steps will reflect this.

Comment: And by cover, you mean will include them e.g. the area of forest cover within smaller buffers inside larger buffers? Thank you!

Comment: I actually have an additional question--I'm now noticing that the tabulate area tool did not include all of the buffers ("zones") in it's analysis, as noted by missing "FID"s in the resulting table. Is there a reason why this would happen and how can I ensure all buffers are included in analysis? Thank you!

Comment: Hi, I'm now having problems where I create a multi-ring buffer with disolve=none, and when I go to tabulate area, it is only given me the info for one buffer and not all three. I'm not sure what is going wrong as this did not happen previously. I need the area within each buffer distance. Please help if you can!