# Batch buffer multiple points but with individual parameters?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, buffer

I am trying to put multiple buffer rings around a series of points (fishnet label points). I want to do a batch of them as there are way too many to efficiently export each point and buffer each one individually, but when I do all the points together, the attribute table comes back with the three buffer rings (250 m, 500 m, 1000 m) listed as just one point, rather than having these three buffer distances for every point put into the buffer tool.

I am wondering if there is a way to obtain the individual buffers for each point, but still put them in together rather than individually?

[image: buffers for label points in purple (ignore buffers in read, done previously and separately)]

[image: buffer attribute table from buffers for label points only showing information for three buffer distances as 1 set of buffers, instead of for each point]

Comment: Do you use modelbuilder? and then you can iterate through each point. see > https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/84989/batch-clip-in-modelbuilder-of-arcgis-for-desktop/84992

Comment: You just need to set the 'Dissolve Option' to 'NONE' in the tool

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determining amount of forest in overlapping buffers using ArcMap?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/310385/determining-amount-of-forest-in-overlapping-buffers-using-arcmap)